# How to set --dart-define in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I'm not able to build and launch the app from xcode alone. Meaning pressing the button "Start the active scheme".

I've tried setting the User-Defined setting `DART_DEFINES` under `Build Settings` for the different schemes accordingly. E.g.:

```
DART_DEFINES
  Debug-at     ENV=at
  Debug-dev    ENV=dev
```

and so on. Picture for clarity:

[image]

When trying this, the build fails with the following error:

> error build: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit
> code

Am I missing something obvious? Are there other ways of passing command line arguments when building/launching from xcode?

Launching the application on an IOS simulator from `VSCode` using the following (in launch.json) works fine:

```
{
    "name": "[dev] myAppName",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "args": [
        "--dart-define", "ENV=dev",
        "--flavor", "dev"
    ]
}
```

Running the following command works fine:

```
flutter build ipa --flavor dev --dart-define "ENV=dev"
```

Comment: VSC's Flutter extension has launch.json, which can be customized to provide specific arguments to the build and run tools.

Comment: Not following you on how that would help me in Xcode? As I tried to explain all is fine if I run from vscode or build from CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okey, so I've finally solved it... To set values corresponding to what is entered using the CLI operator `--dart-define`, and use that when running **from** XCode it is correct to use the `User-Defined` variable called `DART_DEFINES`. What is not obvious is that the value that should be entered there is your value base64 encoded. So in my case, if I use the following from VSCode or CLI:

```
--dart-define "ENV=at"
```

Then the value of `DART_DEFINES` in XCode should be `RU5WPWF0`

When running/building from VSCode or using the CLI to build/run, flutter tools will base64 encode the value and set the value in the runners project file (typically project.pbxproj in Runner.xcodeproj) and the generated files located in the ios/Flutter directory. The files are currently named `flutter_export_environment.sh` and `Generated.xcconfig`. Those files are used when running/building from XCode.

Comment: The value part of each `--dart-define` pair must be base64 encoded ?

Comment: And so, how to add on Xcode ? It would be so nice a visual example from Xcode

Comment: Look at the User-Defined setting DART_DEFINES under Build Settings for the different schemes (or single scheme if you only have one). If you run from VScode first, the variable will most likely contain the appropriate value as xcode will pick it up from the generated file.

Comment: What if we use `--dart-define-from-file=config.json`. How to define config.json in XCode project to take build natively

Comment: The answer does not make it clear where or how to set DART_DEFINES in Xcode

Comment: @Karatekid430, how it is done is described in the question and also partly in the answer. "... setting the User-Defined setting DART_DEFINES under Build Settings for the different schemes..." and "...use the User-Defined variable called DART_DEFINES..."

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a simpler answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984194/passing-dart-environment-variables-in-xcodebuild-build-for-testing-command)

Basically, stay within vscode, and then run `flutter build ios` in config-only mode passing your dart defines.

If it succeeds, you should be able to see your dart defines in Flutter/Generated.xcconfig file (encoded in base64)

(full code and examples in original answer)

Comment: ... and check the comment on the same answer that you linked to and you'll understand why your answer here won't be enough. The dart defines needs to be set in xcode for some cases. Until proven otherwise, I'd say that the answer I've written here is needed when comibining e.g. different schemas for dev/at/prod having a multi-tenant setup in a complete pipeline with deployment to AppStore.

Comment: Don't understand why - 
run "flutter build ios... --dart-define ..."
Then launch from XCode - it's what I'm doing and works

Comment: What do you mean "then launch from XCode"?

Comment: Opened XCode on the Runner project (alongside VS Code), then click the Play (Run) button. Need to make sure you open the `Runner.xcworkspace` and not the `Runner.xcodeproj` one

Comment: ...and how do you plan to do that in a pipeline (as I wrote in my first comment) only via a CLI?

Comment: Either way. I'm satisfied with my answer to my question. If your answer is helpful to others, that's great! It's all about helping others :)

Comment: Sandbagged Sandberg ;-D