# Passing dart environment variables in xcodebuild build-for-testing command

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-integration-test

I'm trying to run my flutter integration tests on firebase test lab. Therefore I'm using dart environment variables to set my login credentials. To setup the ios test version I need to run the following command:

`xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -config Flutter/Release.xcconfig -derivedDataPath ../build/ios_integ -sdk iphoneos build-for-testing`

My question is now how to set the dart environment variables in this command? On the android gradle task it works when I pass the variable as base64 string `-Pdart-defines="${BASE64_STRING}"`. But that doesn't work for me on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Run `flutter build ios` in config-only mode passing your dart defines:

```
flutter build ios --config-only -t integration_test/example_test.dart --debug --dart-define MY_KEY=MY_VALUE
```

If it succeeds, you should be able to see your dart defines in `Flutter/Generated.xcconfig` file (encoded in base64):

```
$ cat ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig | grep DART_DEFINES
DART_DEFINES=TVlfS0VZPU1ZX1ZBTFVF
$ printf 'TVlfS0VZPU1ZX1ZBTFVF' | base64 -d
MY_KEY=MY_VALUE
```

If you do `xcodebuild build-for-testing` now, the dart defines will be compiled into your app.

Comment: This is not helpful for CI/CD which needs to pass the dart defines when running Xcode build